# Solr - query for results with shared related field

Tags: search, solr

In Solr, is it possible to search for documents that share values for a related field?

Say my index contains webpages. The documents might look something like this:

```
{"domain": "example.com", "path": "?page=1", "text": "foo etc etc"}
{"domain": "example.com", "path": "?page=2", "text": "bar more words"}
{"domain": "example.org", "path": "mypoems", "text": "foo is asdf"}
```

I would like the query `foo bar` to return the first two pages, since they both have the same domain. It's ok if the third document is returned as well (since they're all partial matches anyway), but ranked lower.

What's a good way to accomplish this? The best I can think of is creating another index with every page in a `domain` concatenated together, and then running a second query, filtering  for `domain=example.com`.

Is there a better way than this? I'd like to avoid running two queries if possible.

Comment: How would you handle `foo more words` in your `page=2` example? i.e. is it more important that a domain matches all your query values, or that there are two pages for the domain that matches?

Comment: I think I'd prefer matching all the query values. If there isn't a full match in any given domain, solr's out-of-the-box ranking would be fine.

Comment: I think you're having the correct idea, create a secondary index that contains domain and the complete text; that's probably the only way you're going to get proper scoring

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use grouping. Something like this. But that wouldn't give you the ability to rank things reasonably.

```
?q=text:foo bar
&group=true
&group.field=domain
```

Getting back

```json
[
  {
    "groupValue":"example.com",
    "doclist": {
      "numFound":2,
      "start":0,
      "docs": [
        {"domain": "example.com", "path": "?page=1", "text": "foo etc etc"},
        {"domain": "example.com", "path": "?page=2", "text": "bar more words"}
      ]
    } 
  },
  ...
]
```

Alternatively, you could run a facet query first to determine which domains have the most matching pages, and then run a group query to fetch just those domains. That gives you something sort of ranked, but does require two queries.

A third option could be to make use of nested documents. Then you could have your data look like:

```json
{
    "type": "domain",
    "domain": "example.com",
    "pages": [
         {"type": "page", "domain": "example.com", "path": "?page=1", "text": "foo etc etc"},
         {"type": "page", "domain": "example.com", "path": "?page=2", "text": "bar more words"}
    ]
}
```

This would require some experimenting to see if the boosting happens as expected, but I believe it will boost matching parent documents (domains in your case) is multiple children match. Although the queries for nested documents get a little complicated fast!